# How do I leverage naming conventions in a Python codebase to avoid repetitive code without `eval`/`exec`?

Tags: python

I have a number of DataFrames in Python:

```py
[df1, df2, fd3, df4, ...]
```

And a large number of functions that act on them

```py
[clean_df1, clean_df2, clean_df2, ...]
```

```py
[format_df1, format_df2, format_df2, ...]
```

This results in somewhat repetitive code, and I'd love to be able to write:

```py
final_data = {}
for i in [1,2,3,4,5,...]:
    final_data[f'df{i}_final'] = eval(f'df{i}.pipe(clean_df{i}).pipe(format_df{i})')
```

But using `eval` in this way feels wrong and LSP unfriendly...

Is there any functionality in Python to leverage these naming conventions to avoid repetitive code without falling into code-generation/`eval`/`exec` etc...

## Edit

Currently what I have is a few dictionaries:

```py
data_registry = {'df1': df2, 'df2': df2, ...}
cleaning_registry = {'df1': clean_df2, 'df2': clean_df2, ...}
format_registry = {'df1': format_df2, 'df2': format_df2, ...}
```

But keeping these up to date is error prone (forgetting to add one / typos). I suppose my main question is how to auto generate these dicts or something similar (vs. having to manually edit them often)

## Edit 2:

@matszwecja asked for more detail on how these thigns are defined.

To give more context to the question - these are features in a feature engineering pipeline

There is a function that creates a dataframe with the feature

A function that normalizes it (normalization is feature specific)

And a function that takes the un-normalized feature and formats it into a human readable value (also feature specific)

I use dictionaries and not lists because matching on index would be more error prone - say, if two lists didn't get the matching functions in the matching index.

Roughly these are:

```py
def normalize_feature_i() -> pl.Expr:
    return pl.max_horizontal(
        pl.col('feature_i').list.get(0).pipe(_default_descending, -0.03),
        pl.min_horizontal(
            pl.col('feature_i').list.get(1).pipe(_default_descending, -0.03),
            pl.col('feature_i').list.get(2).pipe(_default_descending, -0.03)
        )
    ).alias('feature_i')

def fmt_feature_i(col: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:

    def _fmt_feature_i(x):
        val = min(x)
        i = '' if x[0]==val else '*' if x[1]==val else '**' if x[2]==val else ''
        return f'{val:.0%}{i}'
            
    return col.map_elements(_fmt_feature_i)
```

In some parts of the codebase I want to apply all the formatting to all the features, in others all the normalizations, etc...

I thought of having a `class Feature()` to keep this logic together - but it came across as very messy (the ML code should not care about the visualization code, etc...)

Comment: So all the functions are manually defined, and specific to each dataframe? And some functions may or may not be defined for some dataframes?

Comment: Imagine three teams, data engineering defines the data cleaning functions, some time later the ml team writes a normalizing function, and some time later the UI team writes a formatting function. It's cumbersome to track these functions so we adopted the naming convention.

Comment: In that case I'd probably suggest going with class. You create a parent class with default implementations for all necessary functions (e.g. just return df, or raise an error if that is preffered behavior). Then for each different piece of data, you create inheriting class that implements all the changed functions. It's kinda hard to suggest proper architecture without knowing full details of the project, but less you rely on strings to access proper data, the better.

Comment: I agree. I think for the time being I'll expect each team to keep a register (ie. a dict that maps the feature name to the function meant to process it) and then I'll have some unit tests that use the `function.__name__` vs its key in the dict to sense check that the registries seem correct. Note that I'm not going with a class because I don't want to couple these workstreams that tightly.

Comment: Related: [How do I create variable variables?](/q/1373164/4518341) (sort of a duplicate in some respects, e.g. one answer talks about why not to use sequentially labeled variables, another talks about `getattr()`.)

Comment: Speaking of typos, you have `fd3` in the first list, repeated `*df2`s in the other lists, and `'df1'` containing `*df2`s in the dicts

Comment: Shouldn't the dict be keyed by the feature name, instead of the identifier of the dataframe that contains it? This isn't my field, but that'd make more sense to me. Maybe I don't really understand the process. Like, why are you showing lists if you're not actually using lists? Adding more details might help, like showing your project structure. For tips, see [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Zip your lists together; don't rely on the variable names, but on the references to the associated objects.

```
final_data = {i: df.pipe(c).pipe(f) 
                 for i, (df, c, f) in enumerate(zip(dfs, cleaners, formatters))}
```

(And note that a dict indexed with a contiguous stream of integers can usually be replaced by a list:

```
final_data = [df.pipe(c).pipe(f) for df, c, f in zip(dfs, cleaners, formatters)]
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest looking at the [Adapter pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adapter-method-python-design-patterns/). By creating classes for each distinguishable dataframe format, you could have each clean function inside each dataframe like,

```
@dataclass
Class Df1:
    attr1: int
    attr2: int
    ...
 
    def clean_fn(self):
        ...
```

Since you have every class to implement the same interface say in this case which is clean_fn. You can then have a handler to call the interface to do the job.

It will be more complex but more robust compared to code generation. My then supervisor does love using eval/exec approach for the one-off flexibility to adapt in virtually any situations giving you really high speed of delivery while being hard for your colleague to look at your code and reducing the reusability. You have to consider carefully the tradeoff for your approach.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague pointed me to a solution using `getattr`

```py
from projectlib.models import preprocessing as _repository_of_preprocessing_functions 
from projectlib.presentation import formatting as _repository_of_formatting_functions 

normalization_registry = {feature_name: getattr(_repository_of_preprocessing_functions, f'normalize_{feature_name}') for feature_name in all_feature_names}

formatting_registry = {feature_name: getattr(_repository_of_formatting_functions, f'format_{feature_name}') for feature_name in all_feature_names}
```

Comment: But what if the attribute doesn't exist? You said "some time later the [x] team writes a [y] function", and your code still needs to run in the interim, no? Maybe you'd want to set a default for `getattr()` like `None` or use a try-except so that missing attributes don't get added to the dict.

Comment: Yes, in practice I'll add some try except logic or a filter on the dict comprehension using `hasattr()` - but by the time these registries are being initialized all the relevant functions should have been defined. The issue is more that when I initialize the formatting_registry it's not guaranteed all the normalization functions are defined, and vise-versa (hence why I didn't want to couple the two streams in a `Feature` class).

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be doing that with "naming conventions", but with data structures instead. `for i in [1,2,3,4,5]` should be `for i in range(1, 6)`, or, even better, dynamically defined amount of input dfs, eg. `range(len(dfs))` Dataframes should be loaded into a list, so `df[0] = df0`, `df[1] = df1` etc. This way you can completely get rid of eval. Same with other numbered functions.

```
dfs = [df0, df1, df2, df3, df4]
clean_functions = [clean_df0, clean_df1, clean_df2, clean_df3, clean_df4]

final_data = []
for i in range(len(dfs)):
    final_data.append(df[i].pipe(clean_functions[i]))
```

Comment: I'm doing something very similar, I have data structures where I add all the dfs, all the clean_dfs, and all the format_dfs, but each time I define a function I have to modify all those data structures - it's not the end of the world, but a bit tedious.

Comment: Also `cleaning_registry = {'df1': clean_df1, 'df2': clean_df2, ...}` is so prone to typos... it feels messy

Comment: @MYK In regards to your 2nd comment, that's because you're intent on using dictionaries where they are not needed. Put them in a list and you can by their index, not some arbitrary string which is, as you say, prone to typos. As for the first issue, all you really need to do is append to all the lists whenever there's a new df. It would also help if you showed how all those functions and dfs are defined, because there is a fair chance they could be created already in a list, instead of having to manually put them by name.

Comment: See updated post